# Intent.createChooser selecting the default application

Tags: java, android

i am trying to use Intent.createChooser to let user have a choice to decide which app to open, but its not displaying the app chooser pop up and forcing user to Google Map app when button is pressed, here is code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mapper= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:31.712685, 73.979542?q="+Uri.encode("Home")));
                Intent chooser= Intent.createChooser(mapper,"select app plz");
               startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's Android behavior.

If there is only 1 app can handle this Intent, it opens immediately without showing any chooser.

If there are more than 2, and the last time you choose Google Map and select Always, then it will open Google Map every time later without asking.

Go to `Google Map` app settings and clear default may help

Comment: @EslaBaeny Now if your problem is solved, a vote or mark as answered would help others and gain me the reputation for helping